# How to solve MongoDB memory usage is growing rapidly?

Tags: python, mongodb, memory-management, iot

I did few **IoT projects for a manufacturing company**. For that I used MongoDB as the database for those projects and MongoDB located in company's server. Apart from the usual database writing, person who is responsible for this project, has to issue excel files for business requests. Then he monitored high memory usage in the server and the **RAM of the server is 16GB**. **In a one day now the memory usage is more that 7000MB**.

Then he informed me about this issue.

I tried the following methods, but no method gave a permanent solution.

- Restarting the MongoDB service (result from this is the results that I want to get in a permanent way).
- Tried planCacheClear option also.
- closing the client connection in the Python program
- using a sleep in the loop of the Python program
- used WiredTiger option also but it not limiting the memory usage.

Comment: This question is probably better for dba.stackexchange.com. It's also not clear to me what your goal is. Are you trying to force the database to not fully utilize the resources available to it from the server? What is considered "high" memory usage and what would you like it to be instead?